# How can I make this slide code snippet loop infinetly ( my current code is not working and I don't know where I'm making mistakes)

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file with the following CODE:

```
var slideArray = new Array();
slideArray[0] = new Image();
slideArray[0].src = "images/slide/1.jpg";
slideArray[1] = new Image();
slideArray[1].src = "images/slide/2.jpg";
slideArray[2] = new Image();
slideArray[2].src = "images/slide/3.jpg";
slideArray[3] = new Image();
slideArray[3].src = "images/slide/4.jpg";
slideArray[4] = new Image();
slideArray[4].src = "images/slide/5.jpg";

var step = 0;

function slideit() {
    if (!document.images)
        return;
    document.getElementById('slide').src = slideArray[step].src;
    if (step < 5)
        step++;
    else
        step = 0;
    setTimeout("slideit();", 4500);
}

slideit();
```

This piece of code gets all the images from my directory and sets their path to an image element on the page.

After that I call a function slideit() in the code which iterates through all the images and calls itself afterwards recursively through a call made by a setTimeout() function at every 4500 milliseconds.

The problem is that it doesn't turn on again after it iterates through 4 of my images and it doesn't display the last one and I don't know how to solve this problem. Any advice of code example is welcome, thanks in advance !

Comment: Your condition seems make `step` become `5`, which is out of boundary at `document.getElementById('slide').src = slideArray[step].src;`, so it should throw some error here, you may need to check before you're using it, or change condition check from `5` to `4`.

Comment: I've changed the code to verify if step is less than 4 and now it works very well .... I see where I had my mistake, thanks a lot mate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the length of the array for testing, like here with a reminder operator.

```js
function slideit() {
    document.getElementById('slide').src = slideArray[step].src;
    step++;
    step %= slideArray.length;
}

var step = 0,
    slideArray = new Array();

slideArray[0] = new Image();
slideArray[0].src = "http://lorempixel.com/100/50/";
slideArray[1] = new Image();
slideArray[1].src = "http://lorempixel.com/100/51/";
slideArray[2] = new Image();
slideArray[2].src = "http://lorempixel.com/100/52/";
slideArray[3] = new Image();
slideArray[3].src = "http://lorempixel.com/101/50/";
slideArray[4] = new Image();
slideArray[4].src = "http://lorempixel.com/102/50";

if (document.images) {
    slideit();
    setInterval(slideit, 4500);
}
```

```html
<img id="slide" width="100" height="50" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@fuyushimoya helped me out solving the problem. It seemed that inside the function I was checking step variable to see if it was higher than 5 and that made the function not working properly ... no everything is working fine and and step doesn't get the value 5 anymore which would of made it out of boundary at `document.getElementById('slide').src = slideArray[step].src;` as he stated.

Thanks a lot @fuyushimoya for helping me on this one ! Million thanks !